# Adding rowspan or column span functionality at the table while generating data-table using (React) material table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am generating dataTable using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) plugin in ReactJS. I couldn't find any direct way or option to generate **rowspan** or **column span** at dataTable using the plugin. Is there any way to do it ?

Here is a sample screenshot of what table might look like but will be shown via dataTable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of what you are trying to do is a little bit unclear.

If you want to add something like a button on each row in a col span you can define it in the "columns" prop of your Table like so:

```
columns={[
      { title: 'Update', field: '', render: rowData => <button onClick={() => doSomethingWithId(rowData.id)} className="myTableButtonStyle" /> },
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      ....
    ]}
```

This will add an update button which will call on the doSomethingWithId() function passing the id of the line as a parameter.
Is it what you are looking for? Else would you mind explaining a little bit more what you want?

**EDIT**

Here is what i obtain
[image]

with the following code

```
<MaterialTable
      data={[
        { name: '', nationality: 'British', address: '', country: 'England' },
        { name: 'Noor', nationality: 'American', address: 'California', country: 'US' },
        { name: '', nationality: 'Chinese', address: '', country: 'China' },
        { name: '', nationality: '', address: '', country: '' },
      ]}
      columns={[
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Nationality', field: 'nationality' },
        { title: 'Address', field: 'address' },
        { title: 'Country', field: 'country' },
      ]}
      options={{
        rowStyle: {
          height: '25px',
        },
      }}
      title="Display Data"
    />
```

You don't need to add rows or colspan to achieve this render, just giving the good dataSet and the Columns definition will do.

In your **data** props you need to give a list of objects with all the datas you need.
You then define which datas are displayed where with the **columns** props. if you want a more personalize render in one column (ex: you want to display the country in bold) you can define it by giving a render in the columns object like so:

```
{title: 'Country', field: '', render: rowData => <strong>{rowData.country}</strong>
```

for the empty row to have the same size as others, use props **options** on your table.
Does this help you?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I am trying to add rowspan or columspan, like multiple rows in a single row, not trying to show button or any html element.

Comment: Is the purpose of this to have a treelike table with some parent/childs elements?

Comment: @Palencar....I have added a screenshot of what table should look like.

Comment: @ni8mr I edited my answer given your screenshot, tell me if that is what you were looking for. If This aint enough, try to put some of the code you tried so it can help me understand what you want to achieve.